# Get string text file with start from specify character and end with specify character php code

Tags: php

I have text file with long word in it. I want display in php only some of this word. This word in my text file like this - 
"NASA's Mission Control quickly radioed praise to the six-man space station crew: **"Great work, guys." A brown toy dragon decorated the flight director's desk in Houston. Within minutes, the capsule was outside the NASA-controlled safety zone around the space station and under the complete jurisdiction of the SpaceX team** in Hawthorne, Calif." 
You can see in bold text, i want text after ":" and end with word "team". Anyone can help me for php code for this? Thank you.

Comment: What criteria should be used to split the text?

Answer (score 0):

If the text will **never change**, you can do this like so

```
preg_match('/:(.*?team)/',$text,$hit);
echo $hit[1];
```